# TCP/IP causing WinForm slow response

Tags: multithreading, winforms, tcp

I have a C# WinForm running a TCP/IP server and a client.  when clicking on a button, a TCP client is instantiated to transmit a message, then it is closed.  the server captures the message, and show it on a message box.

question:
my WinForm seems to be interrupted.  it does not always respond to my click (which instantiates the client message transmit method).  I suppose this is due to the server thread?  if so, what can I do to fix this interruption.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your networking is occurring in the UI thread. That's a big problem: the UI thread is meant to stay available to respond to user events.

You should put your networking onto a separate thread, or use an asynchronous API. Don't forget that you can only update your UI from the UI thread though - so you'd typically either use `BackgroundWorker` to report progress/completion on the UI thread, or use `Control.Invoke`/`Control.BeginInvoke` to execute a delegate on the UI thread. You can read up on threading in various books and tutorials - I like [Joe Albahari's tutorial](http://www.albahari.com/threading/).

If you're using .NET 4.5 / C# 5, you can use asynchronous calls to make your life a lot easier - but if you're using an earlier version of .NET, using a separate thread is *probably* going to be simpler.

Comment: I did put my server method on a separate thread, which runs continuously and is closed on Form_Closing().  however, the client method is not on any thread.  it is an instance of TCP client only.  can you tell me which one is the problem creating the problem?

Comment: @hoangnguyen: *All* code runs on a thread. Everything you do is on a thread. It sounds like the problem is that you're creating the `TcpClient`, then sending a message with a blocking call. (It's not clear whether you're sending the data to "yourself" (i.e. the same server) or a different one, by the way.)

Comment: yes, I am using blocking methods to send.  it is TcpClient.Connect(), and NetworkStream.Write().  I am sending it to myself (localhost).  shall I wrap this method on a separate client thread?

Comment: @hoangnguyen: Yes... or have a dedicated thread for all your client communications. As I said in my answer, you need to be careful about accessing the UI though...

Comment: I now run the client method on a separate thread.  it seems to be more responsive, but the intermittent unresponsiveness does not completely go away.  I guess this can't be fixed, as I now have 3 threads in parallel, and 2 of them have blocking methods?

Comment: @hoangnguyen: Well it's hard to know what's causing the unresponsiveness now, without knowing more about what your UI thread is actually doing... but that's usually what you should look at.